# django Choice list (dynamic choices)

Tags: django, multiple-choice, choicefield

i have a choices list :

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
("T-shirts", "T-shirts"),
("Hoodies", "Hoodies"),
("Shorts", "Shorts"),
```

)

but i want to make this list dynamic so i can add and delete choices ,i created a new model **Category**
what i want to do is something like this :

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
for choice in Category.object.all():
    (choice.category, "choice.category"),
 )
```

but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: You can use a `ForeignKey`. In a `ModelForm`, this will use a `ModelChoiceField`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, you should not make use of a `CharField` or some other field with choices, but use a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

For example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class MyModel(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you construct a `ModelForm`, it will use by default a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), and the default widget is a dropdown with the `Category` options.

If you want to select *multiple* `Category`s, you should use a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class MyModel(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

In a filter, you can then use a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`** [readthedocs]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter-and-modelmultiplechoicefilter-arguments):

```
class MyModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    categories = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Category.objects.all()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['categories']
```

But normally, without specifying anything that is the default field it will use.

You can alter the widget to a [**`CheckboxSelectMultiple`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) to work with a sequence of checkboxes:

```
class MyModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    categories = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['categories']
```

Comment: that's exactly what i did  i have a  product model and a category model ,category model is a foreign key in the product model , but  i am using  a filtering form :                                        categories = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='categories', choices=CATEGORIES_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())  so i have to provide the choices in that format ,anyway the for loop does work :for choice in Category.object.all():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Nas: but you do'nt need to. If you want to select multiple ones, you need ot make use of a `ManyToManyField`, since now that will not be able to store multiple categories.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem ok but in the front end  i want to display the choices as a checkbox list how  to do that  with ManyToManyField ??

Comment: @NAS: with a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget, see edit.

Comment: @ Willem thank you the output (checkbox)  works but it does not  filter  is it a problem when i add null= True and blank =True To the ManyToManyField ??

Comment: @NAS: that is not a problem. Are you sure you submit the form accordingly?

Comment: i found the problem ,actually i am using Django widget tweaks to render the form input manually so i can add some style to the checkbox :                                                {% for choice in filter_form.category %}
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{ choice.id_for_label }}" value="{{ choice.choice_label }}" name="category">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ choice.id_for_label }}">{{ choice.choice_label }}</label>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

Comment: it worked fine with the old static choice  list but not with the  ManyToMany Field ,with the static choice list the url parameters looks like this  :?categories=shoes  , the url parameters with the MTM field looks like this:..... ?categories=1 ,so its filtering based  on the primary key and  it does not look very nice

Comment: @NAS: shouldn't `value="{{ value }}"`?

Comment: well django-filter comes with it's own template tags and i am not familiar with it  i just followed a tutorial  and made few changes so it  can work with bootstrap anyway  this is the original template tag : {{filter_form.categories }}  and that's what it renders :<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="1" id="id_categories_0" checked="">
 shoes